# Delphi - How to 'Overload' 'procedure of object' type

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, overloading

Do 'Delphi' provide any means to 'overload' 'procedure of object' type like

```
TTesting = class(TObject)
Public
Type
TInformationEvent1 = procedure( x: integer ) of object; overload ;
TInformationEvent1 = procedure ( x: integer ; y: string) of object; overload ;
TInformationEvent1 = procedure ( x: integer ; y: string; z: Boolean) of object; overload ;
end
```

Can I Overload this TInformationEvent1 function in these three ways?

Comment: You can overload a procedure of object like an ordinary procedure but you are trying to overload a **type** and it makes no sense.

Comment: Can you explain it with a small example.

Comment: What do you want to do? Or is this just curiosity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well sort of. You can define generic types with the same name but a different number of type arguments.

```
type
  TInformationEvent<T> = procedure(x:T) of object;
  TInformationEvent<T1,T2> = procedure(x:T1;y:T2) of object;
  TInformationEvent<T1,T2,T3> = procedure(x:T1; y:T2; z:T3) of object;
```

You would then need to resolve the type argument when you add one of these as a member of a class.

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FMyEvent: TInformationEvent<Integer>;
    FMyEvent2: TInformationEvent<Integer,string>;
  public
    property MyEvent: TInformationEvent<Integer> read FMyEvent write FMyEvent;
    property MyEvent2: TInformationEvent<Integer,string> read FMyEvent2 write FMyEvent2;
  end;
```

These are technically different named types as far as the compiler is concerned but from a developer's perspective you don't need to come up with unique names for each type. Notice the use of the `overload` keyword is unnecessary and is actually a syntax error to use when defining procedural types. `Overload` has a very specific meaning: ad hoc polymorphism. This ain't it.

Note, if you are writing a component or control and wish make these published properties your mileage may vary. The form designer has spotty support for generics.

Answer (score 8):

Different types must have different names, as the comment by @user246408 already says. So you will have to give each of these types a different name, for example:

```
type
  TInformationEvent = procedure(X: Integer) of object;
  TInformationEventS = procedure(X: Integer; Y: string) of object;
  TInformationEventSB = procedure(X: Integer; Y: string; Z: Boolean) of object;
```

Now you can assign *any* method (procedure of object) **with a matching signature** to instances of one of these types. So the *methods you assign* can be overloads, but the *types* can not be overloaded.

Answer (score 3):

[Procedural types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Procedural_Types) of the method pointer kind, like you have shown, are usually needed for typing event properties.

Overloading an event property's type is impossible and would have no use, because an event property is specifically designed to do a single thing.

Overloading of routines on the other hand can be useful, because you want the choice between multiple functionalities.

Otherwise said: the difference between an event handler and other routines is that with event handlers you have no control over the input.

> Can you explain it with a small example?

Yes, I can. Here you have a class with three consecutive properties, each having more functionality than the previous. You as user have the choice to assign one or all of them.

```
type
  TTest = class(TObject)
  type
    TInfoEvent1 = procedure(X: Integer) of object;
    TInfoEvent2 = procedure(X: Integer; Y: String) of object;
    TInfoEvent3 = procedure(X: Integer; Y: String; Z: Boolean) of object;
  private
    FOnInfo1: TInfoEvent1;
    FOnInfo2: TInfoEvent2;
    FOnInfo3: TInfoEvent3;
  protected
    procedure DoInfo(X: Integer; Y: String; Z: Boolean);
  public
    property OnInfo1: TInfoEvent1 read FOnInfo1 write FOnInfo1;
    property OnInfo2: TInfoEvent2 read FOnInfo2 write FOnInfo2;
    property OnInfo3: TInfoEvent3 read FOnInfo3 write FOnInfo3;
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FTest: TTest;
    procedure Info(X: Integer); overload;
    procedure Info(X: Integer; Y: String; Z: Boolean); overload;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TTest }

procedure TTest.DoInfo(X: Integer; Y: String; Z: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnInfo3) then
    FOnInfo3(X, Y, Z)
  else if Assigned(FOnInfo2) then
    FOnInfo2(X, Y)
  else if Assigned(FOnInfo1) then
    FOnInfo1(X);
end;

{ TForm2 }

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTest := TTest.Create;
  FTest.OnInfo1 := Info;
  FTest.OnInfo3 := Info;
end;
```